# selenium: either chrome not reachable or DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, arguments

I am using selenium in Mac and pycharm, and here is the versions I am using:

```
chrome:  Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)
chromedriver: 96.0.4664.45
selenium: 4.1.0
```

and here is the code I am running to scrape a page,

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np


def main():
    pages = np.arange(1, 2, 1)

    for page in pages:

        results = []
        page = "https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/" + str(page)

        sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222 ")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(page)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        for element in soup.find_all('a'):
            name = element.text
            results.append(name)

        print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I comment chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222 "), I get the rror: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist and when I uncomment it, I get the error chrome not reachable.
The code used to work fine with chrome 91, but since it is updated, it does not work anymore. I have tried re-installing, restarting my laptop, and even a different debugging port I found online  ("--remote-debugging-port=12582"), but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Even after trying out almost every solution I found in stackoverflow and even downgrading my chrome, I realized that nothing works. So, instead I installed the [firfox geckodriver for mac](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), and placed it in my /usr/local/bin. but be aware that Mac 11 or higher might not allow it to run, so have a look at this [documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Notarization.html) for a work around.
afterwards you can test the geckdriver following this [medium link.](https://medium.com/dropout-analytics/selenium-and-geckodriver-on-mac-b411dbfe61bc).
Also add the following path to the webdriver.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```