# Google Cloud Run - Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (chrome not reachable)

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-cloud-run

I wrote this question after some days of debugging and research trying to find out another point of view for reaching a good solution for this issue.

As the title says I'm encountering this error when executing **Selenium 4.1.0** with **Chromedriver** and **Chrome** both downloaded from the official website, at its **121.0.6167.85** version inside docker using a virtual display.

My Code:

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()

options.binary_location = "/usr/local/bin/chrome/chrome"
desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",
    options=options,
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
)
driver.get_url("https://google.com")
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

#### Locally it works fine, but in Google Cloud run it outputs:

```
SessionNotCreatedException at -
Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x2a77881e1d93 <unknown>
#1 0x2a7787ec5337 <unknown>
#2 0x2a7787ef9bc0 <unknown>
#3 0x2a7787ef5765 <unknown>
#4 0x2a7787f3fb7c <unknown>
#5 0x2a7787f331e3 <unknown>
#6 0x2a7787f03135 <unknown>
#7 0x2a7787f0413e <unknown>
#8 0x2a77881a5e4b <unknown>
#9 0x2a77881a9dfa <unknown>
#10 0x2a77881926d5 <unknown>
#11 0x2a77881aaa6f <unknown>
#12 0x2a778817669f <unknown>
#13 0x2a77881cf098 <unknown>
#14 0x2a77881cf262 <unknown>
#15 0x2a77881e0f34 <unknown>
#16 0x3e3be06d8fa3 start_thread
```

The files are copied OK in the container in Cloud Run as I've seen them with cloud shell and its permissions are:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16201816 Feb 23 16:34 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16201816 Feb 23 16:34 /usr/local/bin/chrome/chrome`

I have tried changing configuration options such as changing permissions and copying  the binaries directly into the folders and using them instead of downloading and unpacking them in the Dockerfile.

### EDIT:

After Googling a lot I found this post [selenium: either chrome not reachable or DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581506/selenium-either-chrome-not-reachable-or-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist) that described the same issue. Adding `--disable-setuid-sandbox` didn't help and I obtained a timeout. Adding `--remote-debugging-pipe` could also help **for chrome versions > 117** but not in my case, I obtained a timeout error. Finally, as I had to use a proxy in a Raspberry server I'll try to develop a flask server in there to mount the selenium infrastructure.

I hope someone that getting onto this post anytime could be helped by any of the solutions I tried at least.